# Rails 4 - mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, mapping

I have a user model and a profile model.

The associations are:

```
user has_one :profile
profile belongs_to :user
```

I have a user model which I am trying to use to create a profile when a new user is first created. I only want to run this method if the user is new.

I have this callback method in user.rb:

```
after_create :build_profile

  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
    # Profile.save
  end
```

When I save this and go through my authentication process (using devise & omniauth), I get this runtime error:

```
RuntimeError (Could not find a valid mapping for [#<User id: 1, first_name: "Me", last_name: "Ma", email: "me@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$KCZn..HS2GuGjvlcNtfAH/28.DQoWetO...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 16, current_sign_in_at: "2015-12-15 09:57:14", last_sign_in_at: "2015-12-15 09:27:07", current_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:49, last_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:49.195>, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-12-15 09:02:58", confirmation_sent_at: "2015-12-15 08:42:48", unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2015-12-09 23:53:20", updated_at: "2015-12-15 09:57:14", image: nil>, #<Profile id: 1, user_id: 1, title: nil, hero_image: nil, overview: nil, occupation: nil, external_profile: nil, working_languages: nil, created_at: "2015-12-18 21:58:49", updated_at: "2015-12-18 21:58:49">]):
```

I'm not sure what this mapping error means.

I have a user_id integer in my profiles table and it seems to be referencing the relevant user id properly.

I tried adding profile.save to the build_profile method, but the same error is generated, so I don't thing that helps.

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Comment: just a guess but try putting ```devise :database_authenticatable, :timeoutable``` in your user.rb model at the top

Comment: Try to name your `build_profile` method by a different name because it's already reserved by ActiveRecord. Please see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) for more information.

Comment: Hi Van, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but get the same error message as I've set out above.

Comment: Hi Miles, I have database_authenticatabel but I don't have timeoutable. Is that necessary?